# Generar etiquetas con C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy  programando un sistema para generar etiquetas, anteriromente lo relaizaba a traés de código (con la libreria de ZXing) y sus labels también.
Ejemplo de cómo imprimo la etiqueta actualmente:

```
       private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, 
                      System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(generador.GenerarDataMatrix_Gm(StrFinal), 90, 33, 41, 43); /*QRCODE CONFIG*/
       try {
            using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
            {
                using (Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 6))//Formato
                {
                    string caption = string.Format("{0}", "H" + Serial + " (S)");//Texto de la etiqueta
                    g.DrawString(caption, fnt, Brushes.Black, 18, 057);//posicion del texto

                    caption = string.Format("{0}", Conexion.Inter);//Texto de la etiqueta
                    g.DrawString(caption, fnt, Brushes.Black, 18, 49);//posicion del texto

                    caption = string.Format("{0}", comboBox1.Text);//Texto de la etiqueta
                    g.DrawString(caption, fnt, Brushes.Black, 18, 041);//posicion del texto

                    caption = string.Format("{0}", Conexion.Parte);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Printpage     " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de diseñar la etiqeuta con un programa externo, y con la apliación de Windows Forms que desarollo poder imprimr los diseños segun el num de parte que seleccionen(ya que cada número de parte tienen diseños diferentes).

Comment: qué impresora está utilizando? zebra?
Si es así, usted puede realizar creando archivos ZPL externamente y usar en su aplicación

Comment: Estoy Utilizando Intermec,